# Kendo Control calls Controller's action method only from the main page. It does not call it from another page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dropdownbox

I have an `index.cshtml` view that uses a shared layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

This `index.cshtml` view is displayed when user opens the Login page of the application. It works with the Login controller

This layout generates a partial view that defines a Kendo.DropDownList:

```
@Html.Partial("_CultureSelector")
```

This is the `_CultureSelector` view with a dropdown list:

```
<script>
    function onCultureChange(e) {

        ChangeCulture(e, this);
    }

    function onDataBound(e) {
        var combo = $("#culture").data("kendoDropDownList");

        $(combo.dataItems()).each(function () {
            if (this.IsDefault) {
                e.sender.value(this.Value);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<label for="culture">Choose culture:</label>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("culture")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataTextField("DisplayText")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("PopulateCultures", "CultureSelector");

            }).Events(e => e.Error("CheckError"));
        })
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Select("onCultureChange").DataBound("onDataBound");
        })
)
```

I have a controller called "CultureSelector" with a method "ChangeCulture":

```
public JsonResult ChangeCulture(string selectedCulture)
{
    Session["SiteUICulture"] = selectedCulture;
    Session["hasCultureChanged"] = true;
    GlobalCulture.SetCultureCookie(selectedCulture);
    Session["CultureDropDownSelected"] = true;

    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I change the value in dropdown, this method is called, but ONLY on Login page.

This is an Ajax call to "ChangeCulture" method:

```
function ChangeCulture(e, cultureDropDown) {

    var loginUrl = document.location.origin + '/Login';
    var returnUrl = document.location.pathname + document.location.search;

    if (e.item) {
        var selectedCulture = cultureDropDown.dataItem(e.item);
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "CultureSelector/ChangeCulture",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                data: { "selectedCulture": selectedCulture.Value },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert("test");
                        window.location.href = returnUrl;
                    }

                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

When I change the dropdown valued on Login Page string "test" is printed on `Ajax` success, when on "Forgot Password" page, it is not printed.

Login page has "Forgot Password" link and when it is clicked, "ForgotPassword" page is opened.

This page uses the same  layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

So, the same dropdown list is generated. `PopulateCultures` method is called.

But, when changing the value in dropdown, `CultureChange` method is not called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "page is opened"...what does that mean?

Comment: Just a typo. I changed it

Comment: My guess is that you have declared "culture" twice and the binding is not working.